# assembly:SuppressMessage for CS8981

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to suppress warning CS8981 for migrations.
I tried like this, but it doesn't work:

```cs
[assembly:SuppressMessage(
    "Microsoft.Naming", "CS8981:The type name only contains lower-cased ascii characters.",
    Justification = "Migrations can be named anyhow.",
    Scope = "namespaceanddescendants", Target = "My.Namespace.Database.Migrations.Migrations")]

namespace My.Namespace.Database.Migrations.Migrations
{
    public partial class appointmenttypeassignments : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
```

I don't know what is wrong. Maybe category is incorrect? Can not find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/warning-waves#cs8981---the-type-name-only-contains-lower-cased-ascii-characters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute?view=net-8.0) `SuppressMessageAttribute` can be used only to disable the  [code quality rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/) and according to the list there `CS8981` is not one of them. You can disable it with preprocessor directive (in file or only concrete instance):

```
#pragma warning disable CS8981
```

Or via [`NoWarn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#nowarn) compiler option:

```
<NoWarn>CS8981</NoWarn>
```

Comment: `<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CS8981</NoWarn>` is better as it doesn't clobber any other warnings that may be configured elsewhere in the project, such as in `Directory.Build.props`.